# How can I implement GUI into my code?

Tags: java, user-interface

So I just finished this project I was doing for fun. I have a basic understanding of GUI, but not all to much and haven't actually put it into one of my projects. I am not sure how I would implement this all into my code but can people give me suggestions or at least point me in the right direction?

The Game is HangMan.

Code: 
    public class HangMan
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    String mysteryGuess = "hello";
    String userGuess = "";
    int wrongGuesses = 0;
    boolean[] guessed = new boolean[mysteryGuess.length()];

    System.out.println("Hello and welcome to Hang Man!");
    loop:
    for(;;){
        String[] wordAsArray = convertToStringArray(mysteryGuess);

        for (int i = 0; i<wordAsArray.length;i++)
            if(wordAsArray[i].equals(userGuess))
                guessed[i]=true;
        System.out.println("Word so far:" + visibleWord(wordAsArray,guessed));
        System.out.println("What is your guess?");
        userGuess = sc.next();
        boolean guessResult = guess(userGuess,wordAsArray,guessed);
        if (guessResult==(true))
            System.out.println("Correct");
        else{
            System.out.println("Incorrect");
            wrongGuesses++;
        }
        if (didWin(guessed)==true)
            break loop;
    }
    System.out.println("Good Job! The word was " + mysteryGuess);
    System.out.println("You only got " + wrongGuesses + " wrong!");
}


//This method creates an array version of the parameter word
//For example, if word contained the data "hello", then this method
//would return {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}
//Parameters:   word - a single word
//Returns:      an array containing each letter in word
public static String[] convertToStringArray(String word) {
    String [] pWord = new String [word.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i<pWord.length; i++){
        pWord[i] = word.substring(i,i+1);
    }
    return pWord;

}


//This method determines whether the player has won the game of HangMan
//Parameters:   guessed - array of boolean values
//Returns:      true - if every value in guessed is true
//              false - if at least one value in guessed is false
public static boolean didWin(boolean[] guessed) {
    boolean bGuess = true;
    loop:
    for (int i = 0; i<guessed.length;i++){
        if(guessed[i]==false){
            bGuess = false;
            break loop;
        }


    }
        return bGuess;
}


//This method determines what portion of the hidden word is visible
//For example, if the parameters are as follows:
//     wordAsArray: {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}
//     guessed: {true, false, false, false, true}
//Then the method should return "h???o"
//Parameters:   wordAsArray - the individual letters to be guessed
//              guessed - array of boolean values; a true value means the corresponding letter has been guessed
//Returns:      A string representing how much of the word has been guessed (unguessed letters are represented by ?'s)
public static String visibleWord(String[] wordAsArray, boolean[] guessed) {
    String visibleWord="";
    String[] holder = new String [wordAsArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i<holder.length;i++)
        holder[i]=wordAsArray[i];
    for(int i = 0; i<holder.length;i++){
        if (guessed[i] == true)
            holder[i]=holder[i];
        if (guessed[i] == false)
            holder[i]="?";
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<holder.length;i++){
        visibleWord=visibleWord+holder[i];
    }
    return visibleWord;
}


//This method checks to see if a player has made a successful guess in the game of Hang Man
//For example, if the parameters are as follows:
//     letter: "e"
//     wordAsArray: {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}
//     guessed: {true, false, false, false, true}
//Then the guessed array would be changed to:
//      guessed: {true, true, false, false, true}
//And the method would return false
//Parameters:   letter - the letter that the user has just guessed
//              wordAsArray - an array of individual letters that are to be guessed
//              guessed - array of boolean values; a true value means the corresponding letter has been guessed
//Returns:  true - if letter matches an unguessed letter in wordAsArray
//          false - otherwise
public static boolean guess(String letter, String[] wordAsArray, boolean[] guessed) {
    boolean appearsAtLeastOnce=false;
    for(int i = 0; i<wordAsArray.length;i++)
        if(letter.equalsIgnoreCase(wordAsArray[i])){
            guessed[i] = true;
            appearsAtLeastOnce=true;
        }
    return appearsAtLeastOnce;



}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking?

Comment: _"How can I implement GUI into my code?"_ - Start by going through the [Swing tutorial trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to transfer a console program to a GUI program is not an easy task if you've never made a GUI program before. You need to learn about event-driven programming. I suggest you have a look at the [**Swing tutorials**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

---

Some tips though. It you want a **"semi-gui"** program. You can just use `JOptionPane`s for the input. Say you want to get an number input. You would do something like this

```
String numberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a Number");
int number = Integer.parseInteger(numberString);
```

once you do the first line, an input pane automatically pops up. asking for an input. The result is a String, so you *have* to parse it to get a number.

Also if you just want to *diplay* a message, just use

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

You can do that do display some result. In the above case when you just want to show a message, you don't need to make it equal to anything. So instead of the `System.out.println()`s, you can just use the `JOPtionpane.showMesageDialog()`, and instead of `scan.next()`, you would use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`

Comment: Nit Pick - This is a personal thing, but I can't stand the use of `JOptionPane` in this manner, as it doesn't actually teach anything about how to actually make a GUI - but that's just me

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's why I linked the Swing tutorial and said _"semi-gui"_ :)

Comment: If I missed it, what do you think the OP will see ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer duly noted. Bold wrapping has highlighted the key words :)